# Include all javascript files in a directory to a html file in angularjs? with grunt?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

In my AngularJS app, I've many controllers js files.

These controllers (`one.ctrl.js`,`two.ctrl.js`,`...`) needs to be included in my `index.html` file.

**Directory Structure:**

```
app/
   js/
      controllers/
         one.ctrl.js
         two.ctrl.js
```

Currently, above `js` files are included in `index.html` file as follows.

**index.html:**

```
<!--   other html components   -->

<script src="js/controllers/one.ctrl.js"/>
<script src="js/controllers/two.ctrl.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

There are gonna be more `*.ctrl.js` files which are required to be included in `index.html`.

I need a way to automatically include all the `*.ctrl.js` files in `controllers` directory to `index.html`.

**Findings:**

From some SO questions,

[Load JavaScript and CSS files in folders in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605770/load-javascript-and-css-files-in-folders-in-angularjs)

[How can I include all JavaScript files in a directory via JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175008/how-can-i-include-all-javascript-files-in-a-directory-via-javascript-file)

I found that it cannot be done automatically and needs some server side scripting or build tools.

**My Question:**

Currently, I'm using `yeoman` which include `grunt` for build tool.
So, my question is, How can those javascript files in a directory be automatically included in a html file?

Comment: I can give you an example with gulp.js. Will that do?

Comment: I haven't used `gulp.js`. I can try if it does the job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the [grunt-include-source](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-include-source) plugin

Using it you can define templates like these :

```
html: {
    js: '<script src="{filePath}"></script>',
    css: '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{filePath}" />',
  }
```

in your html file which will be expanded to include all your source js and css files present in your source location which can be configured in the grunt task

Comment: Can you provide a full Gruntfile.js ?

Answer (score 7):

Answering the general question of adding source files to index.html on demand and automatically and elaborating on the use of [grunt-include-source](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-include-source).

This is for the following folder structure:

```
MyProject
|
+-- index.js
+-- Gruntfile.js
+-- package.json
+-- //other files
|
+--+ app
   +-- //app files (.html,.js,.css,.*)
```

1. Install with `npm i -D grunt-include-source grunt-contrib-watch`.
2. In your `Gruntfile.js`, add `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');`
3. Then you have to add a bunch of tasks to your `Gruntfile.js`, after which it should look like this:

   ```
   module.exports = function (grunt) {
       grunt.initConfig({
           pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
           //...
           watch: {
               //...
               includeSource: {
                   // Watch for added and deleted scripts to update index.html
                   files: ['app/**/*.js','app/**/*.css'],
                   tasks: ['includeSource'],
                   options: {
                       event: ['added', 'deleted']
                   }
               }
           },
           includeSource: {
               options: {
                   //This is the directory inside which grunt-include-source will be looking for files
                   basePath: 'app'
               },
               app: {
                   files: {
                       //Overwriting index.html
                       'app/index.html': 'app/index.html'
                   }
               }
           }
       });

       //...
       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-include-source');

       //...
       //Include sources, run the server, open the browser, and watch.
       grunt.registerTask('default', ['includeSource', 'watch']);
   };
   ```
4. In your `index.html`, add this (**the file path here looks inside the base path set in `Gruntfile.js`**):

   ```
   <!-- include: "type": "css", "files": "**/*.css" -->
   <!-- /include -->
   <!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "**/*.js" -->
   <!-- /include -->
   ```
5. Finally, on the command line:

   ```
   grunt
   ```

This should start off all tasks in sequence, and your index.html should be updated accordingly when a JS or CSS is added or removed.

This is how your `index.html` might look like with a small number of files:

```
<!-- include: "type": "css", "files": "**/*.css" -->
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- /include -->
<!-- include: "type": "js", "files": "**/*.js" -->
<script src="_routes/routes.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- /include -->
```

Links:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-include-source
- https://ajsblackbelt.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/free-from-include/
- https://jhipster.github.io/tips/002_tip_include_js_grunt.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
(function loadScript() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var done = false;

    var directory = 'libraries/';
    var extension = '.js';
    var files = ['functions', 'speak', 'commands', 'wsBrowser', 'main']; 

     for (var file of files){ 
        var path = directory + file + extension; 
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = path;

        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // attach to both events for cross browser finish detection:
        if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
           this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {
           done = true;
           // cleans up a little memory:
           script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
           // to avoid douple loading
           head.removeChild(script);
        }
    };
  head.appendChild(script); 
  done = false;
 }
})();
```