# How do I mock dom elements when using mocha javascript?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm using mocha to test my JavaScript code. The code involves html and css and implements a chat app. As far as I saw, Mocha can test JavaScript functions by matching the expected value to the function's return value.

But what if I want to test functions that don't return a value? Functions that mainly deal with DOM elements. (Like appending an image for example ).

How exactly can I mock DOM elements in mocha and then test if the function succeeds in generating the appropriate DOM elements?

I had looked around and found it was possible with selenium webdriver and jsdom. Is it possible to do this test with **mocha alone** and no other additional interfaces?

Comment: JSDom is the right tool. Why would you prefer to avoid it?

Comment: Some example tests using JSDom (using Jest, which has a similar API): https://github.com/ripjar/material-datetime-picker/blob/master/lib/js/__tests__/index-test.js#L37

Comment: I was told to use mocha alone...But thanks anyway

Comment: Can you use an assertion library (e.g. chai) as well? mocha doesn't give you a way to make assertions about your code.

Comment: I don't think I can.. Just mocha. Are you saying it's impossible?

Comment: Mocha is only a test _runner_; it needs another library to describe _how_ your code should work. If you run your tests in Node you can use `assert` for that... but you'd need JSDOM there. Bundlers like browserify may give you a port of `assert` for running tests in the browser. However, most people use a richer assertion library like chai. Are there any other tests in your project? How do they describe the code's behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSDOM is convenient because it allows you to test against a "real" DOM implementation without the overhead of running in a web browser.

If you can [run your unit tests inside a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857778/how-do-you-run-mocha-tests-in-the-browser) you can assert against the DOM in the same way:

```
describe("the super special button", () => {

  it("adds an image", (done) => {
    const button = document.querySelector(".js-super-special");
    button.click();

    // give the browser a chance to update the DOM
    setTimeout(() => {
      const image = document.querySelector(".js-image")

      // using assertion library, like chai
      expect(image).to.not.beNull();

      // or using a port of Node's `assert` from a bundler like browserify:
      assert(image != null);

      done();
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: I had already tried using document.querySelector before. When I ran npm test it said "document is not defined". How can you reslove this error? It works on my code but doesn't work when I run this as mocha testing code.

Comment: It sounds like you're running your tests in Node. In that case, you really do need JSDOM (because Node doesn't know what `document` is by itself). In a browser, this test will work against the "real" DOM.

Comment: I decided to run the tests inside the browser. That way I don't use any external interfaces such as JSDom or selenium webdriver. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fake DOM APIs in nodejs context, and make them global on before hooks of mocha.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  const dom = new JSDOM(
    `<html>
       <body>
       </body>
     </html>`,
     { url: 'http://localhost' },
  );

  global.window = dom.window;
  global.document = dom.window.document;
});
```

Read more here: https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/improve_unit_testing_with_mocha_chai_jsdom

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global) package  alternative that also works outside of Mocha. mocha-jsdom still works, but jsdom-global is better supported.

```sh
npm install --save-dev --save-exact jsdom jsdom-global
```

modify npm test script to be:

```json
"test": "mocha -r jsdom-global/register"
```

test example: `app.test.js`

```js
import {JSDOM} from 'jsdom'; // can also use common js

describe('DOM', () => {
  it('should log selector list', () => {
    const dom = new JSDOM(
      `<html>
         <body>
           <div class="card">1</div>
           <div class="card">2</div>
           <div class="card">3</div>
         </body>
       </html>`,
     {url: 'http://localhost'},
    );
  });

  global.document = dom.window.document;
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.card'));
});
```