# Is there a way to start Mocha tests from a React UI?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm setting up a testing framework for my Node.js application, and I have my Mocha tests already set up and working.

I wanted a UI for my test suite where I can select check boxes to determine which tests should be in the current execution. I have already created a UI for this with Reactjs.

Is there any way for me to trigger and start my mocha test suite through a Reactjs button onClick on the UI? (I do not want to test the React UI, I want the UI to start the Mocha tests which test a different application)

I am looking for a way to run Mocha either through the web or programmatically. React has made this a bit of a challenge since I used the create-react-app command. Attempting to add Mocha via index.html results in an issue since node_modules is outside of the public directory, and attempts to require mocha programmatically result in an error saying there is no constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run mocha tests in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857778/how-do-you-run-mocha-tests-in-the-browser)

Comment: This unfortunately did not fit my use case, as the react configurations will not allow the index.html file to reference files outside of the public folder.

However, I was able to get Mocha to work programmatically by following this documentation: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically

I had to make a slight change though due to the way that react imports the package. Require the Mocha package like so:

import Mocha from 'mocha';
let mocha = new Mocha.Mocha();

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to make using Mocha in web via script tags work, however after some tinkering I was able to get Mocha to work programmatically.

I followed the documentation for this use case, though I had to make a slight change to get the constructor to work: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically

Rather than this (resulted in an error regarding the constructor):

```
var Mocha = require('mocha')
var mocha = new Mocha();
```

I did this:

```
import Mocha from 'mocha';
let mocha = new Mocha.Mocha();
```

This allowed me to create an instance of Mocha and make calls to the different Mocha functions. This was from within the generated App.js file made by create-react-app.